# What is the force exterted on a Iron cylinder when expsed to an Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

is there a way to find the approximate force exerted on a iron cylinder of dimensions (height 1cm, radius 0.5 cm) when it is placed in a magnetic field (Generated by a solenoid). I am trying to make a rail gun kinda thing to pull a 30N weighted object vertically up.